# how to get total number of orders placed by a customer in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, orders

I want to show the total count that how many orders are placed by a customer at "my orders" tab in magento 2 front end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="helper" helper="Ktpl\Contentbyzone\Helper\Data::getLabel"></argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and then create

> Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Ktpl\Contentbyzone\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

/**
 * CMS Page Helper
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getLabel()
    {
        $count = count($this->getOrders());
        return "My Order(".$count.")";
    }

    public function getOrders()
    {
        $customerId = $this->_session->getCustomer()->getId();
        $this->orders = $this->_orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $customerId
        )->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        );
        return $this->orders;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: should i have to override the block class of sales order history to display the count at my orders tab.because i am not able to see the count at my orders tab its showing from the core files sales order history only.can u help me out why i am unable to show the count.

Comment: i am not able to see block class Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface in core files

Comment: thanks for u r help,its working fine for me,after changing the block class to Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current.

Comment: Which magento version you are using ?

Comment: i am using magento2.1.6ce

Comment: i need a small help vaibhav. how can i move that order count towards right side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject **Sales Collection Factory class**

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
protected $orders;
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    .......
) {
    ...
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    ........
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getOrders()
{

    if (!$this->orders) {
        $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->setOrder('created_at','desc');
    }
    return $this->orders;
}
```